# A sequence $u_n = \frac{3}{M-n+1}$, where n and M are positive intergers and $M+1>n$, prove that the sum $S_n>\frac{3n}{M}$?

Tags: real-analysis

A sequence $u_n = \frac{3}{M-n+1}$, where n and M are positive intergers and $M+1>n$, prove that the sum $S_n>\frac{3n}{M}$

Comment: Did you mean $S_n < 3n/M$ instead?

Comment: @IAmNoOne, no it is >

Comment: This cannot right. If $n = 1$, then $S_1 = u_1 = 3/M$.It cannot be strictly greater than $3(1)/M$

Comment: Actually I noticed you haven't accepted a single answer in any of your question. You aren't gonna get any serious response on this site.